# javascript convert Date to this format '2019-01-19T19:11:00'

Tags: javascript, date

From the server I get '2019-01-19T19:11:00.000Z'  I need to convert to local timezone, so that I end up with '2019-01-19T11:11:00'.  My UTC offset is 8 hrs.

new Date('2019-01-19T19:11:00.000Z') produces Sat Jan 19 2019 11:11:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time), how do I get it back to '2019-01-19T11:11:00'?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.toISOString().split('.')[0]);
```

Comment: Not cool. This generates a UTC timestamp that masquerades as local, it doesn't do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You want the date string in iso format, respecting the local time zone:

```js
const tzoffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

const d = new Date('2019-01-19T19:11:00.000Z')

console.log(new Date(d - tzoffset).toISOString().split('.')[0])

console.log('2019-01-19T11:11:00')
```

Comment: `var d = new Date();   d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset());   d.toISOString().slice(0,19);`. ;-)